# meaning of the phrase "be all" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context:

> You would not catch me wearing a suit in my job - it **is** **all** t-shirts and jeans for us!

Was the word *all* used there as a synonym to the word *only*?

Comment: This is the basic meaning of *[all](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/all_4)*, meaning *wholly* or *completely*. *Only* would give the slight implication of some kind of restriction (whether official or just social) that forbade clothes other than t-shirts and jeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It's all" is a bit of an idiomatic expression, a sort of casual slang term.
As the earlier commenter said "This is the basic meaning of all, meaning wholly or completely. Only would give the slight implication of some kind of restriction". True.

"It's all good" means "Everything is good", or "Everything is fine."
"It's not all rainbows and butterflies" means "Everything is not composed of rainbows and butterflies, the world has problems."
"I'm all about that bass 'bout that bass, no treble" means "The bass, that is certainly what is important."